# Performing reverse-clip/difference point from polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, clip, point-in-polygon, differences

I am trying to clips the GeoJSON with points outside of GeoJSON with polygons.

In QGIS 2.18.2 `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference` deletes the geometry but keeps the attributes of the points.

The hacky way is to use `Vector > Research Tools > Select by Location` to select all points inside the polygons and then delete them.

Comment: Maybe it is a symmetrical difference: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#symmetrical-difference

Answer (score 1):

You can select directly the points that you are interested in with "Select by location" by using the geometric predicate "disjoint". If you would rather use the Difference tool, it seems to create an empty GeometryCollection as geometry for the points which are inside a polygon.

[image]

You can select all those features with the "Select by expression" tool and then delete them.

[image]